# How to change colors of a boxplot in octave?

Tags: octave, boxplot

I want to plot 9 distributions using boxplot in Octave. In order to make it more readable, I expected to able to change the inner colour of boxes, or the blue line surrounding it.

Looking at the source code, I realize that colours are hardcoded.

A matlab solution would be[1](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/122426-change-color-of-a-box-in-boxplot):

```
a = get(get(gca,'children'),'children');   % Get the handles of all the objects
t = get(a,'tag');   % List the names of all the objects     
box1 = a(7);   % The 7th object is the first box
set(box1, 'Color', 'g');   % Set the color of the first box to green
```

Is there a similar procedure for octave? Or any other hints?

thanks in advance,
alan

Comment: Since those colors are hardcoded, not easily. You will have to navigate the figure structure and change the colour there. Alternatively, you could modify boxplot to have those options.

Comment: Would you give an example of how to navigate in the figure structure?

Comment: No. Figure structures are like a maze to me (I rarely do plots). But if you don't want to write your own boxplot function, and you don't want to change the code of the existing boxplot, then that's the only option you have left. Have fun.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you are almost there. The following works for me for a single boxplot:

```
b = boxplot(data);
c = get(gca,'children');
for i=1:size(c)
  set(c(i), 'color', 'g');
end
```

The above snippet colors the whole boxplot `g`reen. You can set the color of the individual `c(i)`'s to your liking.